# This keyword anonymous function JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Me pueden explicar lo siguiente teniendo:

```
/* MenuCommand class, a command object. */

    var MenuCommand = function(action) { // implements Command 
      this.action = action; 
    };
    MenuCommand.prototype.execute = function() { this.action(); };
```

> If the action method uses the this keyword internally, it has to be wrapped in an anonymous function. Here is an example of that:

```
var someCommand = new MenuCommand(function() { myObj.someMethod(); });
```

Por qué si se utiliza `this` se debe usar una función anónima al pasar la función como parámetro

Answer (score 0):

no entiendo bien tu pregunta, pero lo que estas haciendo ahí es pasar a la instancia de la clase una función la cual se asigna como **propiedad** a la clase con el nombre **action** esta funcion (action) luego la invocas desde un método de la clase llamado execute, si pasamos esto a ES6 te quedaría así

```
class MenuCommand {
  constructor(callback) {
        this.action = callback
    }


   execute() {
        this.action(); // utiliza () ya que invocas a la funcion que pasaste como callback en el constructor
    }
}

x = new MenuCommand(function() {
  console.log('hola')
})

x.execute()
```

utilizas this, ya que asignaste tu función anónima como propiedad (**action**) global de la clase, la cual luego llamas en el método execute

Class
https://javascript.info/class

Callback
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Es para mantener el contexto: Si la función a la que quieres llamar hace referencia a otro objeto, al pasarla como parámetro este contexto se pierde, ya que this pasará a ser el objeto de la clase MenuCommand. Ejemplo: Tenemos ese objeto con un método y un atributo:

```js
const obj1 = {
  atributo: 'Hola',
  metodo: function () {
    console.log(this.atributo);
  }
}

obj1.metodo();
```

Ahora usemos ese método con tu código:

```js
const obj1 = {
  atributo: 'Hola',
  metodo: function () {
    console.log(this.atributo);
  }
}

obj1.metodo();

var MenuCommand = function(action) { // implements Command 
  this.action = action;
  this.atributo= 'otra cosa';
};
MenuCommand.prototype.execute = function() { this.action(); };

const com = new MenuCommand(obj1.metodo);
com.execute()
```

La solución es crear una llamada así:

```js
const obj1 = {
  atributo: 'Hola',
  metodo: function () {
    console.log(this.atributo);
  }
}

obj1.metodo();

var MenuCommand = function(action) { // implements Command 
  this.action = action;
  this.atributo= 'otra cosa';
};
MenuCommand.prototype.execute = function() { this.action(); };

const com = new MenuCommand(() => obj1.metodo()); //función flecha anónima
com.execute()
```